# Save pandas DataFrame without repeating index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, save

I would like to set 2 columns of a dataframe to be its indecies. However, I don't want it to repeat it in each row.

For example, I have a following dataframe, `df`:

```
  Object  Size   Color Ornament
0      A     1     red      yes
1      A     3     red      yes
2      A     4     red       no
3      B     1  yellow      yes
4      B     3  yellow      yes
5      B     4  yellow       no
6      C     1   green       no
7      C     3   green       no
8      C     4   green      yes
```

I would like to set the index to be *Object* and *Color*, so I do `df = df.set_index(['Object', 'Color'])`. In the output I get:

```
               Size Ornament
Object Color                
A      red        1      yes
       red        3      yes
       red        4       no
B      yellow     1      yes
       yellow     3      yes
       yellow     4       no
C      green      1       no
       green      3       no
       green      4      yes
```

However, after saving file using `df.to_csv('file.csv')`, I am getting file like:

[image]

How can I save file to be like the output in console? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot directly, you would need to cheat and manually hide the duplicated values. Does it really make sense? Then the CSV would be missing values.

Comment: So, there is no function within pd.to_csv that can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably not such a good idea (this will make an CSV with missing data) you can use:

```
cols = ['Object'] # list of columns for which to "hide" the duplicates

(df.assign(**{c: df[c].mask(df[c].duplicated(), '')
              for c in cols})
   .to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
)
```

Output CSV:

```
Object,Size,Color,Ornament
A,1,red,yes
,3,red,yes
,4,red,no
B,1,yellow,yes
,3,yellow,yes
,4,yellow,no
C,1,green,no
,3,green,no
,4,green,yes
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I found out that saving as excel workbook does the job.